# rosjava_core build error ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compile'

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I tried building rosjava_core as per [1], but it always gives me the same build error. I will present the steps I took to hopefully tell you enough to be able to help me.

1. I start out with a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on vmware.
2. I install ROS electric (ros-electric-desktop-full) following the steps from [2].
3. I install the Android SDK (but I don't think this is of relevance for rosjava_core to build correctly).
4. I install gradle and mercurial via apt-get (sudo apt-get install mercurial gradle).
5. I install the Sun JDK 6u35 64-bit (because I read somewhere else that OpenJDK could turn out to be a problem if libraries are missing) and set it as my Java SDK. I also tried this step with OpenJDK as my SDK.
6. I follow the instructions on [3] to install the rest of the other software and initialize my workspace.
7. This is the step where it fails. When I execute "./gradlew install" [4], I get the following error message:

---

---

---

user@ubuntu:~/my_workspace/rosjava_core$ ./gradlew install

> Building > :apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':apache:apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compile'.

> Could not resolve group:org.apache.commons, module:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient, version:3.1.0.
> Required by:
> ros.rosjava_core:apache_xmlrpc_common:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not GET 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom'.
> Could not resolve group:org.apache.ws.commons, module:ws-commons-util, version:1.0.1.
> Required by:
> ros.rosjava_core:apache_xmlrpc_common:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not GET 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/ws/commons/ws-commons-util/1.0.1/ws-commons-util-1.0.1.pom'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6 mins 25.964 secs

---

---

I would be very grateful if somebody could point out what I need to do it right to build rosjava_core. Cheers, Bernd

---

[1] http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

[2] http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu

[3] http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html

[4] http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42748/rosjava_core-build-error-%27:apache_xmlrpc_common:compile%27/) by [Bernd Kampl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3118/bernd-kampl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The better solution is to use the "mavenCentral()" (similar to "mavenLocal()") method. This change will be applied everywhere soon.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I found a solution to this, although it might not be perfect.
In the folder "rosjava_core" open up the file "build.gradle" and on line 39 replace

```
url 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public'
```

with

```
url 'https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public'
```

and then it will compile.

---

Originally posted by [Bernd Kampl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3118/bernd-kampl/) with karma: 76 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2